# How can i find milkdown data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, markdown, mdxjs

I just setup **milkdown** for the first time and implement basic setup like [see this examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/ngkiq):

But now i can't find data (try console.log still not found).

So how can i find data to use in my Project, can anyone help me out of this?
#TIA

Default data **"# Milkdown :heartpulse: React"** it should be transform into (mdx to text/code) **Milkdown heart_icon React** and after transform i want to find this value in console.log() but can't find it.

Comment: Do you give it any data to work with?

Comment: Not yet, cause it has default data (i mentioned above), where i will provide any kind of data that's why i just want to see default data in console but can't see.